# About h.264 sps, pps

Tags: h.264

I got a h.264 byte stream.

```
1350E94 : 00 00 01 67 42 00 1F 9D  | ...gB...
1350E9C : B8 14 01 6E 9B 80 80 80  | ...n....
1350EA4 : 81 00 00 00 01 68 CE 3C  | .....h.<
1350EAC : 80 00 00 00 01 06 E5 01  | ........
1350EB4 : C1 80 00 00 00 01 65 B8  | ......e.
1350EBC : 00 00 03 02 67 F5 09 7F  | ....g...
1350EC4 : FF FC 3D 14 00 0D 79 39  | ..=...y9
1350ECC : 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39  | 99999999
1350ED4 : 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39  | 99999999
1350EDC : 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39  | 99999999
1350EE4 : 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39  | 99999999
1350EEC : 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39  | 99999999
1350EF4 : 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39  | 99999999
```

SPS = 00 00 01 67 ... 81 00
PPS = 00 00 01 68 ... 80 00
right?

I know SPS, PPS have 3 or 4 byte pattern.

SPS is obviously 3 bytes, But what is bytes of PPS?

00 00 00 01 68? or 
00 00 01 68 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `00 00 00 01 68`? or `00 00 01 68`?

Both are correct. Any NALU (sps, pps, aud, sei, idr, whatever) can have a 3 OR 4 byte start code.